# Table of Oracle DB versions supported by newest ODBC driver

Tags: oracle, odbc, versioning, compatibility

I want to know which ODBC driver version is recommended for Oracle 9 and 10.

Is there official Oracle document that says that newest version of Oracle ODBC driver can or even should be used with older servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not certify ODBC drivers separately (unlike JDBC drivers).  Rather they are certified as part of the client.  So ODBC driver 9.2.0.x is certified to connect to the same database server versions as client version 9.2.0.x.

Oracle test both ways (old client to new server, new client to old server) but only against the supported versions.  In this context what constitutes a supported version varies for server and client.

If you have a Support contract you should check out MOS (formerly Metalink) article on  [Client/Server Interoperability Support Between Different Oracle Versions (ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&doctype=BULLETIN&id=207303.1).   But the headline is, if you are using 9.2.0.4 or higher at both ends you're probably safe.

Comment: Thank you. Can you update link to: https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&doctype=BULLETIN&id=207303.1

There is also "Supported ODBC Configurations On Windows": https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&doctype=BULLETIN&id=66403.1